# MVC .NET Core web API XML or JSON

Tags: c#, json, xml, asp.net-mvc, .net-core

I would like to create a web application that returns data in the form of XML or JSON, how do I go about doing this?

The model:

```
namespace ReturningJSONandXML.Models
{
    public class SomeImportantInformation
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Information { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The controller:

```
namespace ReturningJSONandXML.Controllers
{
    public class GetInfoController : Controller
    {
        // GET: /<controller>/
        public List<SomeImportantInformation> Get()
        {
            List<SomeImportantInformation> ImportantInfo = new List<SomeImportantInformation>();
            ImportantInfo.Add(new SomeImportantInformation { ID = 0, Information = "Awesome info" });
            ImportantInfo.Add(new SomeImportantInformation { ID = 1, Information = "Some other interesting info" });
            return ImportantInfo;
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to return an XML and JSON file...

What are the best practice's I should be using here?

Comment: the api will convert the response to whatever you put on your request header... application/json or application/xml

Comment: If you are using MVC 6 (ASP.NET Core) the framework will automatically negotiate the content (returning the appropriate content-type as @NicoRiff said). More info [inside the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/formatting#content-negotiation).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The framework takes care of this automatically for you so that you don't have to reinvent the wheel. The answer is quoted below.

But to make it simpler: Unless you specify an `Accept` header, the API will serialize the response as JSON. If you specify, for example, `'application/xml'` it will return XML.

As MSDN Says:

> Content negotiation (*conneg* for short) occurs when the client
> specifies an [Accept
> header](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html). The
> default format used by ASP.NET Core MVC is JSON. Content negotiation
> is implemented by `ObjectResult`. It's also built into the status code
> specific action results returned from the helper methods (which are
> all based on `ObjectResult`). You can also return a model type (a
> class you've defined as your data transfer type) and the framework
> will automatically wrap it in an `ObjectResult` for you.
>
> ...
>
> Content *negotiation* only takes place if an `Accept` header appears
> in the request. When a request contains an accept header, the
> framework will enumerate the media types in the accept header in
> preference order and will try to find a formatter that can produce a
> response in one of the formats specified by the accept header. In case
> no formatter is found that can satisfy the client's request, the
> framework will try to find the first formatter that can produce a
> response (unless the developer has configured the option on
> `MvcOptions` to return 406 Not Acceptable instead). If the request
> specifies XML, but the XML formatter has not been configured, then the
> JSON formatter will be used. More generally, if no formatter is
> configured that can provide the requested format, then the first
> formatter that can format the object is used. If no header is given,
> the first formatter that can handle the object to be returned will be
> used to serialize the response. In this case, there isn't any
> negotiation taking place - the server is determining what format it
> will use.

From MSDN -- [Current version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/formatting) and [version at time of quote](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/blob/b2cdf7ff05b4e0449a797c122eb08fb55a18c5b8/aspnetcore/web-api/advanced/formatting.md).

Answer (score 2):

In ASP.Net Core 2.0, you can use an even shorter syntax.

In the `Startup` class' `ConfigureServices` method, you should have:

```
services
    .AddMvc()
    .AddXmlSerializerFormatters();
```

And the controller that accepts complex objects looks like this:

```
[Route("api/Documents")]
public class DocumentsController : Controller
{
    [Route("SendDocument")]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SendDocument([FromBody]DocumentDto document)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

This is the XML it would accept:

```
<document>
    <id>123456</id>
    <content>This is document that I posted...</content>
    <author>Michał Białecki</author>
    <links>
        <link>2345</link>
        <link>5678</link>
    </links>
</document>
```

And the same as JSON:

```
{
    id: "1234",
    content: "This is document that I posted...",
    author: "Michał Białecki",
    links: {
        link: ["1234", "5678"]
    }
}
```

And that's it! Sending the same document either in XML or JSON to `api/documents/SendDocument` endpoint will just work. Just remember to include the correct `Content-Type` header in your request.

For more content, you can read the whole post at my blog:
http://www.michalbialecki.com/2018/04/25/accept-xml-request-in-asp-net-mvc-controller/

Answer (score 1):

with core 2, you need to specifically add the options to the mvc serverice to enable xml input/output:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc(options =>
        {
            options.InputFormatters.Add(new XmlSerializerInputFormatter());
            options.OutputFormatters.Add(new XmlSerializerOutputFormatter());
        });
    }
```

and then change the Accept header to:

application/xml
or 
application/json