# How to display SwaggerResponse in XML instead of JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, swagger-ui

I want to display a response in Swagger UI in XML format instead of JSON. How I can achieve this? This is the code I want to adapt:

```
[SwaggerResponse((int)HttpStatusCode.OK, Type = typeof(FeedModel))]  
public async Task<IActionResult> GetCompanyPostFeed(Guid companyId)
{
    var feed = new FeedModel();

    // Some database requests

    return Content(feed, "text/xml", Encoding.UTF8);
}
```

Comment: Maybe try setting the input/output formatters? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44371198/mvc-net-core-web-api-xml-or-json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try decorating the method with an attribute `SwaggerProducesAttribute` as described [here](https://blog.kloud.com.au/2017/08/04/swashbuckle-pro-tips-for-aspnet-web-api-part-1/):

```
[SwaggerProduces("text/xml")]
[SwaggerResponse((int)HttpStatusCode.OK, Type = typeof(FeedModel))]  
public async Task<IActionResult> GetCompanyPostFeed(Guid companyId)
```

In keeping with the dislike of link-only answers, I'll reproduce some of the relevant bits of that article here:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class SwaggerProducesAttribute : Attribute
{
    public SwaggerProducesAttribute(params string[] contentTypes)
    {
        this.ContentTypes = contentTypes;
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> ContentTypes { get; }
}

public class ProducesOperationFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(Operation operation, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry, ApiDescription apiDescription)
    {
        var attribute = apiDescription.GetControllerAndActionAttributes<SwaggerProducesAttribute>().SingleOrDefault();
        if (attribute == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        operation.produces.Clear();
        operation.produces = attribute.ContentTypes.ToList();
    }
}
```

Then in SwaggerConfig.cs, you'll need something like:

```
config
    .EnableSwagger(c =>
        {
            ...
            c.OperationFilter<ProducesOperationFilter>();
            ...
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the method `GetControllerAndActionAttributes` does not exists, I use ASP.NET Core 2.1 and Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger 3.0.0

Comment: @frank_lbt - it's an extension method, and not that complicated; you may be able to roll your own for .NET Core: https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/blob/master/Swashbuckle.Core/Swagger/ApiDescriptionExtensions.cs