# How to implement a Swashbuckle IOperationFilter that processes custom attributes in .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1, swashbuckle, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I have implemented a `Swashbuckle.Swagger.IOperationFilter` to process custom attributes as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52948376/13087

I now want to do something similar for `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 5.0.0`.

It seems that the `ApiDescription` class does not have the extension method `GetControllerAndActionAttributes` that was uses in the original implementation.  I tried reimplementing it by looking at its [source code](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/blob/master/Swashbuckle.Core/Swagger/ApiDescriptionExtensions.cs), but it uses members `ApiDescription.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor` and `ApiDescription.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes<TAttribute>` that I don't appear to exist for .NET Core.

Can anyone help get me started by showing me how to get hold of custom controller and action attributes from an `IOperationFilter`?

**Update**
It looks like the .NET Framework implementation has an `ActionDescriptor` that is actually a [ReflectedActionDescriptor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/hh834789(v%3Dvs.118)).  This class has a constructor that takes a `MethodInfo`, which is used to find the attributes.

But I don't see any way to get a `MethodInfo` for the .NET Core implementation [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions.ActionDescriptor](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Mvc/Mvc.Abstractions/src/Abstractions/ActionDescriptor.cs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found my answer: there's an extension method `ApiDescription.TryGetMethodInfo` that will get the `MethodInfo`and hence give access to custom attributes.

Comment: It looks like this extension method `TryGetMethodInfo` does not exist in older versions of Swashbuckle. If you're stuck on an old version like me, try `ApiDescription.ControllerAttributes()` and `ApiDescription.ActionAttributes()`.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I do on .NET 6 for the OpenApi version implementation.This example is to use the System.ComponentModel Description Attribute for my swagger documentation for the method.
Create Class that implements IOperationFilter

```
public class CustomSwaggerOperationFilter : IOperationFilter {        
    public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context) {
        if (context.MethodInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false)?.FirstOrDefault() is DescriptionAttribute descriptionAttribute) {
                operation.Description = descriptionAttribute.Description;
        }          
    }
}
```

Then when configuring swagger in Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(options => {
        options.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo {
            Version = "v1",
            Title = "My API",
            Description = "My Api Description"
        });
        options.OperationFilter<CustomSwaggerOperationFilter>();
    });
```

Now inside of the controller over the Action I can just use the Description attribute, and the operation filter will make swagger use it
Example Method in some controller

```
[HttpGet]
[Description("Description for my Method Goes here")]        
public async Task<SomeResponseModel> Get(CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
// Do Stuff here for response
}
```

I use pattern matching and you could further customize and add other attributes, or even attributes you create yourself and repeat the process for finding the attribute and the value you which to use for your swagger docs. Hope this helps others, as most answers were older versions of .net core

Answer (score 0):

Use code like this:

```
var attributes = apiDescription.GetControllerAndActionAttributes<AuthorizeAttribute>();
if (!attributes.IsNullOrEmpty())
{
    var param = new Parameter
    {
        name = "Authorization",
        @in = "header",
        description = "Bearer + access token",
        required = false,
        type = "string"
    };

    if (operation.parameters == null)
        operation.parameters = new List<Parameter> { param };
    else
        operation.parameters.Add(param);
}
```